# Deleting all rows older than 5 days

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to delete all rows older than 5 days, in my table.

My table have a createdOn column of type date can u suggest me the query.

I m using mySql database

now i wrote folloiwng query

```
SELECT * from `user_games` where created_on >= DATE_SUB(created_on, INTERVAL 5 DAY)
```

to see the user_games which are five days old

but always i m getting same result even when i run query for Invterval 1 Day or Interval 5 day

[image]

while today curdate is 2011-5-2

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this,

```
delete from mytable where datediff(now(), mytable.date) > 5
```

This would be proper approach to delete.

Comment: Runs much faster than Harry Joy's answer below, not sure why.

Comment: @iautomation I'd guess this is more efficient as datediff() only considers the date while DATE_SUB() takes the time into consideration as well.

Comment: Sorry for replying to myself, but note that:
DATEDIFF('2007-12-31 00:00:01','2007-12-30 23:59:59') = 1 day while DATE_SUB('2007-12-31 00:00:01','2007-12-30 23:59:59') = 2 seconds.

Answer (score 12):

Use [date_sub](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) function like:

```
delete from `myTable` where createdOn<DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 5 DAY);
```

Comment: `SELECT *` should be `DELETE`

Comment: @bdares: Yes I know I was just updating that.

Comment: i m not getting desired results  , i tried to see data by using select rather than delete , just to see whether desired rows get picked by query or not , but i m not getting right result

Comment: +1: Will be able to use an index if one exists on the `createdon` column

Comment: hey it is not working appropriately, once i saw the query i think , yes  i got the right sql code now , but when i run it ir always returns same resutls ,i have updated the resutls in my question the query given by sanjay found to be work perfectly , i m also amazed by this behaviour of three different queries

Answer (score 2):

You want to do this:

```
delete from myTable 
where createdOn < CurDate() - 5
```

Comment: +1 The addition is standards compliant and easier to read than `DATE_SUB` imho :)

Comment: This will not work i have tried it earlier, currdate-5 returns some integer which in turns deletes every 2 days old rows, and this results in issues.

Comment: That's funny, always worked with me. That's `createdOn`'s datatype?

Comment: ya Adrian i understand it's ur opinoin , wat i found by running query i told u , and i got the desired results by query given by Sanjay. It's not matter of few points but what is more imp is that if we found a new thing/concept/logic then it is better.

Comment: +1: Will be able to use an index if one exists on the `createdon` column

Comment: I think the timing of comments betrayed us. By stating my opinion I was referring to @andomar's comment. You do have to choose as answer whatever solves your problem, which is what you did.

Comment: Did NOT work for v5.6.. I tried a SELECT before-hand and it returns all the rows.

Answer (score 0):

DELETE FROM table_name WHERE `time` < (NOW() - INTERVAL 5 DAYS)