# Wondering if its possible to have a file running and checking if a value in database/row

Tags: php, sql, row, verification

Basically, If a value in Row is same for 3 days I want to remove the column, like if someone hasn't verified their account remove the account to save space.

Is there a way to make a script for this?
If so can someone help me make it?

Comment: are you using a linux system?

Comment: you want to remove a column, not a row?

Answer (score 0):

Have a column like

```
modified timestamp default current_timestamp on update current_timestamp
```

in your table. Then write a query to delete entries of the table and execute it via [event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a [cron job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16144350/executing-a-php-script-with-a-cron-job) to run every day and execute this query on the database:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE insert_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND NOW();
```

Note: similar problem [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853543/deleting-all-rows-older-than-5-days)